# Graph database embedded on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, graph-databases, triplestore

What options exist for running a graph database embedded on iOS?

Given the apparent lack of options would it be best to try to manage the DB in sqlite and just keep the database size small?

Comment: What are you looking to use the graph database on the device for? Can it be something that is hosted off site and called from the device over the network?

Comment: You can fake a small one with SQLite or some such, but likely anything of any size should be hosted elsewhere -- it can be a real storage hog.

Comment: Unfortunately it must not rely on the network.  About how small is small -- will hundreds of thousands of edges fall in that category?

Comment: Just based on gut feel, I'd guess somewhere between 100,000 and 1,000,000 edges would be the practical limit, depending, of course, on specifics of the design and how clever you are.

Comment: Is this something that will be persistent or will it be in memory?

Comment: That rough estimate is very helpful.  I was hoping to make the database persistent, but your point is a good one.  It may be workable to hold relational data and minimal graph data in SQLite, process it in memory with Graph.Boost or something nicer and then use a Java Graph Database for any large scale server based needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DEX Graph DB by Sparsity Technologies was made publicly available a few days ago, for iOS platform (and also BB10). It's free for evaluation and development.

As it is a beta-release a registration is required prior to download. You can try it at:

http://www.sparsity-technologies.com/dex_downloads

DEX mobile beta offers the C++ API for both the iOS & BB10 platforms.

Comment: Dear Pere can you answer this link becouse i had confusion related to above link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294821/is-core-data-is-a-kind-of-graph-database/29295536#29295536